# How to upgrade pypy itself?

Tags: python, pypy

I've installed `pypy` by `conda`:

```
conda create -n pypy37 pypy python=3.7
```

and pypy version is:

```
Python 3.7.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (44db2626, Oct 29 2021, 16:19:11)
[PyPy 7.3.7 with GCC Clang 11.1.0]
```

Now I want to upgrade `pypy` itself, not `python` version, is there any command can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conda` (and `PyPy`) have dropped support for `pypy3.7`. I would recommend you build a new environment with

```bash
conda create -n pypy39 pypy python=3.9
```